# How to take automatic backup of latest code or latest version of Project from TFS to local machine

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am suffering with difficult problem in my project. My question is that, Is it possible to take automatic backup of latest code or latest version of entire project solution from TFS in visual studio 2012.

my need is first take automatic backup of latest version of code & after that mapped it in to another directory/folder. i want to do that with batch process but i  didn't know how to make  batch file for take automatic backup/copy of one folder and mapped it into another folder

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can you describe what kind of problems you're trying to prevent?

Comment: I just want to get latest version of my project/ solution  or code on my local machine without Regular action like right click on solution-->get latest etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the reasoning behind your request, but it's quite simple to create a Batch script that will create a temporary mapping and then downloads all the files from TFS. You could also look into [`git tf`](https://gittf.codeplex.com/), if having local undo is the feature that you're after.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524175/736079