# TFS Specific Changeset files to be merged with latest version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I am in the following situation:

A Team Member worked on a task which was partially done in few changesets, few months back. These changesets were reverted and many more changes are done on same files in subsequent changesets.

I want to get the latest version of code (which I have taken) and have some option to get the older changesets (even I can merge changesets one by one) and merge it.

Though I find option to changeset GetThisVersion which gives me whole old codebase. I don't find relevant option in Visual Studio 2010. It would be great to have GUI option and not command line one.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get specific version of a file from file history (view or get specific version) or with command line [Need command to get a file from TFS without a workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175830/need-command-to-get-a-file-from-tfs-without-a-workspace). But to get a folder (project, solution) state seems to be necessary to have a workspace [How to get specific version of folder from tfs without creating a workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432634/how-to-get-specific-version-of-folder-from-tfs-without-creating-a-workspace). 
 I don't think that there is a possibility to merge an old and newer version. When I want to resuscitate some old code I use view in history and copy/paste.