# Get a file from TFS without creating workspace (Using commandline)

Tags: command-line, tfs

I want to get a specific file from TFS server without creating any workspace.
I found a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175830/need-command-to-get-a-file-from-tfs-without-a-workspace). But it seems the view command is not working for me. i have tried the below command.

> ./tf view -s:http://tfs.com:8080/tfs/WTQA '$/MyProject/test.txt' > /test-view/test.txt

but it says "An argument error occurred: The command 'view' is unknown."

Answer (score 1):

This might sound obvious, but have you checked what is actually being run for ./tf?

Try

```
./tf /?
```

and ensure that it correctly identifies as the Team Foundation Version Control Tool, and that it lists the available commands, "view" being one of them.

You should be able to then run

```
tf view -s:http://tfs.com:8080/tfs/WTQA /output:test.txt '$/MyProject/test.txt'
```